# How to properly combine C++ and Python code in boost::python extension module?

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I am trying to create Python extension module that combine both C++ and Python code. So far I was able to run Python code fine but I can’t find a way for my Python object to appear as part of my module import. What am I doing wrong?

Here the example code for my C++ module (I am omitting C++/boost::python code that bind C++ function and classes for clarity):

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE( my_module ) { 
  <... some boost::python code to bind C++ classes/functions ...>
  boost::python::object main_module = boost::python::import("__main__");
  boost::python::object main_namespace = main_module.attr("__dict__”);
  boost::python::exec("aaa = 'ABC’\n”, main_namespace, main_namespace);
}
```

And later in Python if I try:

```
import my_module
print my_module.aaa  <— error!
```

(I know that I can separate python files and C++ dynamic libs in to its own files and it will all work, but i really need my extension module to be just one file for other technical reasons)

Answer (score 1):

```
boost::python::scope().attr("aaa")="ABC";
```

Comment: Yes, i know about this workaround but i really want to execute arbitrary Python code (developed by third parties) as part of my module. So far i even tried to create dummy submodule, execute python in it and copy all objects back - its *almost* works ("import something" and "from something import thing" does not got copied that way)

Comment: @WorkPerNap: But you're modifying the main module's namespace, not my_module's namespace.